# What's the best way to store "spreadsheet data" in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm looking to store spreadsheet type data in a mysql database.  Basically it would be a grid, with x/y coordinates, and each cell can have various different properties to it.

The grids can be of all different sizes, and I'd like this system to be fast and flexible, though some sort of caching isn't out of the question if necessary.

Finally, a requirement of this project is to use mysql, and a restriction against any document style storage solutions(anything nosql really).

I'm curious if anyone has any sort of standard solution for this that I'm not seeing.  I'd like to avoid a big table along the lines of column1_data1 column1_data2 column1_data3 etc etc for however many columns I can safely account for.

Comment: Sounds like an [EAV model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model)

Comment: @Phil: Should make that an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for an [Entity-Attribute-Value model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model)

Comment: while I see EAV as a good way of implementing the extra data each cell needs, we still have the problem of an unknown number of columns and rows.  This would mean each cell itself would need to be an EAV with it's own EAV of custom data related to that cell.

that felt like an overly complicated way of doing it.

Comment: @Nodren You would need to implement two levels of entities, sheets and cells.